# Does PHP have any extension/lib that allows you to use .NET (C#) resources (sources) in PHP code?

Tags: c#, .net, php

Does PHP have any extension/lib that allows you to use .NET (C#) resources (sources) in PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP on Windows has both [.NET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dotnet.php) and [COM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php) facilities.